# UIScrollView SetContentSize with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm taking UIScrollview in storyboard and apply autolayout in it. Inside UIScrollview, I am inserting contentview as autolayout for UIScrollview need one contentview. Now, as per my app scenario I have to change contentView height, so programmatically I had changed autolayout of contentView.

Now I get **contentView's height = 445** after changing autolayout programmatically. Below is my code

```
//----set height of content view----//
CGRect contentViewFrame = contentView.frame;
contentViewFrame.size.height= viewMainContent.frame.origin.y+viewMainContent.frame.size.height + 20 ;
contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
_contentHtConstraint.constant = contentView.frame.size.height;
```

Depending on this **UIScrollview's height is also 445**. But **contentSize of UIScrollview will be 675**.

Can anybody say me how to manage contentSize?

Comment: did you call  `[self updateViewConstraints]`?

Comment: @zhubch No..Where i have to call this ?

Comment: call this after you changed the constraints.

Comment: @zhubch not useful..still having same issue

Comment: @zhubch Having issue in scrollview's contentSize not in scrollview's height //----set height of content view----//
             CGRect contentViewFrame = contentView.frame;
             contentViewFrame.size.height= viewMainContent.frame.origin.y +viewMainContent.frame.size.height + 20 ;
             contentView.frame = contentViewFrame;
             _contentHtConstraint.constant = contentView.frame.size.height;
             
             _objScroll.contentSize = CGSizeZero;
             [self updateViewConstraints];

Answer (score 0):

Add height constraint to your content view. and set outlet for it. 
If you want your content height to be changed when view controller launch. set it in viewWillLayoutSubviews

```
- (void) viewWillLayoutSubviews{
        [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

        //Update your content view height, by updating constant size of height constraint
       self.contentViewHeightConstraint.constant = 1000;//set this value as per your need. 

       // update your view constraint if needed
       [self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

      //Set content size for your scrollview 
      [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.contentViewHeightConstraint.constant)];

}
```

Comment: From your solution scroll content size is now managed, but user interaction on that is disable. I'm not able to do anything there.

Comment: Nilesh.. I'm not using default scrollview. Here I'm using TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollview

Comment: I just checked TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView on github. Its subclass of UIScrollview. you can use default scrollview properties for TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView as well. Check your scrollview or content view User interaction is enabled or not. or might be any other view is overlapping your content view. Check structure for Views.. Hope this might helped you